# Page break characters for more/less

Tags: less, more

I am on Mac OS. I have a C++ program that generates 1000+ lines of data that I redirect to a file. I then use `less` / `more` to go through the file. I'd like to have `less` pause at user-defined chunks of data instead of of pausing every screenful. I thought I could use the `^L` character to mark page breaks, but even after adding them in my C++ code with

```c++
        printf("control-l \n");
```

the `less` command on my Mac will still pause at every screenful instead of at each control-L.

I remember from decades ago that this worked on Unix. Do I need to do something different here?

Comment: Why would your code do a ^V before the ^L  ?  That's not what the binary stream would expect.

Comment: The ^V is to allow my vi editor to accept the next character as a ^L. I'll remove it. It's confusing.

Comment: `more` typically does this, but not `less`. The current `util-linux` version of `more` pauses at formfeeds by default; perhaps the macOS version behaves differently...

Answer (score 1):

Not a page break, but the 'u' and 'd' keys can be set to scroll the screen however many lines you want. By default, pressing these keys scrolls the file by half a screen 'u'p and 'd'own. But if you type a number before pressing either key, both keys will start scrolling the file by the number of lines you specified.

```
less file:
  10d ; scrolls the file down 10 lines
  d   ; scrolls the file down another 10 lines
  u   ; scrolls the file up 10 lines
  25d ; scrolls the file down 25 lines
  d   ; scrolls the file down 25 lines
  u   ; scrolls the file up 25 lines
  5u  ; scrolls the file up 5 lines
  d   ; scrolls the file down 5 lines
```

Note: I'm using the GNU version of less on Debian Linux. The Mac version could be different.

Comment: The Mac version behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

`less` doesn’t pause at formfeeds, but you can achieve the same effect by *searching* for them: <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>n</kbd> to jump to the next formfeed, or <kbd>N</kbd> to go back to the previous one.